# Discord.JS bulkDelete 14 day Error Preventation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How would I stop a purge command using `bulkDelete` in Discord.JS from sending an error if it is over 14 days old? As it spams the console and it's pretty annoying. I have already tried putting it in a try/catch block but it didn't help.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Code:

```js
 if (Number.isNaN(+content)){;
            message.channel.send('Please enter a valid numerical digit.')
        } else{
            if(message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')){
                try{
                    if(content > 100){
                        message.reply("Unable to purge. Limit is 100.")
                    } else{
                        message.channel.bulkDelete(content)
                        
                        
                        message.reply(`successfully purged ${content} messages.`)
                        .then(msg => {
                        msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
                        .catch(console.error)
                        })
                    }
                }catch(error){
                    message.reply(`There was an error.`)
                    console.log(error)
                }
            } else{
                message.reply("You lack the required permissions to do that. (Required Permissions: ``MANAGE_MESSAGES``)")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.bulkDelete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) accepts a second argument (a boolean) which if set to `true`, filters messages to remove those older than two weeks. The default value is set to `false`.

The following should work as expected:

```js
message.channel.bulkDelete(content, true)
```